# Why is plot not generating all of my points?

Tags: r, plot

When I use the plot command to plot 900 points only 30 are being selected. Specifically the 30 "parent" points to base my Matern cluster algorithm on early in my code. I am generating a Matern cluster process with a specified amount of points because I need to make a comparison between different plots. Hence why I am not using spatstat functionality. Furthermore, all points seems to be weighed towards lower values on the y axis and I cannot figure out what is going on.

I initially generate the landscape I am working with by defining the dimensions of the plot.

```
xMin<--0
xMax<-1000
yMin<--0
yMax<-1000
```

Then I define the radius of my clusters, I opt out of using a poisson distribution because I need a set number of points so intensity is not specified.

```
radiusCluster<-0.1
```

Then I calculate the extension on my window for points falling outside the observational window.

```
rExt<-radiusCluster
xMinExt<-xMin-rExt
xMaxExt<-xMax+rExt
yMinExt<-yMin-rExt
yMaxExt<-yMax+rExt
xDeltaExt<-xMaxExt-xMinExt
yDeltaExt<-yMaxExt-yMinExt
```

Then I define the number of parent points and their locations in the window.

```
numbparents<-30
xxParent<-xMinExt+xDeltaExt*runif(numbparents)
yyParent<-yMinExt+yDeltaExt**runif(numbparents)
```

Then I define the number of daughter points and their cartesian co-ordinates

```
numbdaughter<-30

theta=2*pi*runif(numbdaughter)
rho=radiusCluster*sqrt(runif(numbdaughter))
xx0<-rho*cos(theta)
yy0<-rho*sin(theta)
```

Then I replicate the parent points positions the same amount as the daughter points, and transform the co-ordinates to generate the clusters.

```
xx=rep(xxParent,numbdaughter);
yy=rep(yyParent,numbdaughter);

xx=xx+xx0;
yy=yy+yy0
```

However, when I plot this, even though there are 900 points, only the parent points are being generated. Furthermore, most are near the bottom of the y axis, each time I do the plot, which I do not understand because I have used a random number function so they should be evenly distributed across the plot.

```
plot(xx,yy,xlab='x',ylab='y',col='blue')
```

[image]

What do I need to do to plot all of the points, and for the runif to plot an even distribution across the range specified?

Comment: Not sure what you trying to achieve, but you only have 30 unique x,y positions: `nrow(unique(cbind(xx, yy)))` gives 30

Comment: I didn't go through all the code but if the *first* code line is `xMin<--0`, meaning to assign `-0` to a variable, and this strange assignment repeats 2 lines latter, then there must be other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 30 unique values in the sample data.  This can be seen with the following (comment by @zx8754)

```
nrow(unique(cbind(xx, yy)))
[1] 30
```

The reason this is happening is that the random function `runif` is being called once and then the same number is used repeatedly by `rep` which results in duplicate values being calculated.  This is shown with the following example that returns the same value multiple times:

```
set.seed(7)
rep(5 + runif(1), 5)
[1] 5.988909 5.988909 5.988909 5.988909 5.988909
```

Here is one way to use `replicate` to call the random functions multiple times to get unique results.

Values from question:

```
set.seed(7)

xMin <- 0
xMax <- 1000
yMin <- 0
yMax <- 1000
radiusCluster <- 0.1
rExt <- radiusCluster
xMinExt <- xMin - rExt
xMaxExt <- xMax + rExt
yMinExt <- yMin - rExt
yMaxExt <- yMax + rExt
xDeltaExt <- xMaxExt - xMinExt
yDeltaExt <- yMaxExt - yMinExt
numbparents <- 30
xxParent <- xMinExt + xDeltaExt * runif(numbparents)
yyParent <- yMinExt + yDeltaExt ** runif(numbparents) # not sure if ** is typo
numbdaughter <- 30
```

Using `replicate` to generate new numbers for each daughter

```
xx <- as.vector(replicate(numbdaughter, xxParent + radiusCluster * sqrt(runif(numbdaughter)) * cos(2 * pi * runif(numbdaughter))))
yy <- as.vector(replicate(numbdaughter, yyParent + radiusCluster * sqrt(runif(numbdaughter)) * sin(2 * pi * runif(numbdaughter))))
```

Verifying 900 unique values produced:

```
nrow(unique(cbind(xx, yy)))
[1] 900
```